# How to fill missing values in pandas using shift at specified intervals?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, missing-data

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
+---------+---------+
| Value A | Value B |
+---------+---------+
| 10       |       1 |
| 20       |       2 |
| 30       |       3 |
| 40       |       4 |
| 50       |       5 |
| 60       |     NaN |
| 70       |     NaN |
| 80       |     NaN |
| 90       |     NaN |
| 100      |     NaN |
+---------+---------+
```

and I want to fill these the missing values with previous values but shifted like shown below.

```
+---------+---------+
| Value A | Value B |
+---------+---------+
| 10       |       1 |
| 20       |       1 |
| 30       |       2 |
| 40       |       2 |
| 50       |       3 |
| 60       |       3 |
| 70       |       4 |
| 80       |       4 |
| 90       |       5 |
| 100      |       5 |
+---------+---------+
```

The problem is that I these missing values could be in either column. I tried to do it manually but that would take a lot of time. Also filling values depend on `len()` of the column A. My approach was something like this:

```
missing_data_len = len(valueA)-len(valueB)
df['ValueB'].shift(missing_data_len)
```

and then use `ffill` to fill in NaN vlaues. but results are not accurate. Is there a better approach to solve this.

Comment: `df['ValueB'].shift(missing_data_len)` is an issue straight away. This does not work inplace so it's just thrown away

Comment: "but shifted like shown below.". What you've shown is not a `shift`. Shift just move values about, you're instead replacing `NaN` with values. Why should `20` now have a corresponding value of `1` when it was previously `2`?

Comment: It sounds like your NaNs have no consistency, so there is no general rule to apply on how to fill them, so how do you expect python to fill them?

Comment: @Aryerez we know len of both columns if we shift last value in column B by the diff_len-1 and then do it for remaining values as well. and then fill the NaNs using ffill or bfill.

Comment: @roganjosh i just tried that and some other, I know this was wrong but for idea what was i trying to do. May be there is a much better way, an efficient one. "Why should 20 now have ....?" because its supposed to be like this original data frame has wrong mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
null=df['Value_B'].isnull()
r=(len(df)/null.sum())
df['Value_B']=df.loc[~null,'Value_B'].repeat(r).reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
   Value_A  Value_B
0       10      1.0
1       20      1.0
2       30      2.0
3       40      2.0
4       50      3.0
5       60      3.0
6       70      4.0
7       80      4.0
8       90      5.0
9      100      5.0
```

Comment: very well, Sir, do you think i can use it to fill in missing coordinates in my earlier question?

Comment: It may be, I still don't know exactly what you are looking for. I am glad to help